# error in Python: Global name not defined

Tags: python

I keep getting error global name not defined "sizeGreater".

Here is my program that I've come up with so far:

```
import random

def main():
    another = 'y'

    while another == 'y' or another == 'Y':
        again = raw_input("Would you like to generate 1000 random numbers? (Enter y for yes and n for no)")

        generate_numbers()
        difference_numbers(sizeGreater, sizeLess)


def generate_numbers(): 
    numbers = []
    for value in range (1000):
       numbers.append(random.randint(1,100))
    print (numbers)

    numbers2 = [i for i in numbers if i>=50]

    sizeGreater = len(numbers2)
    print ("The numbers at or above fifty are:", sizeGreater)

    numbers3 = [i for i in numbers if i <=50]

    sizeLess = len(numbers3)
    print ("The numbers at or below fifty are:", sizeLess)

    return sizeLess
    return sizeGreater

def difference_numbers(sizeGreater, sizeLess):

    total = sizeGreater - sizeLess
    print total


main()
```

Comment: Your second "return" statement is unreachable. If you wanted to return 2 values you could always return a tuple like this `return (sizeLess, sizeGreater)` but even that wouldn't solve your problem as it looks like you are trying to return values that are then globally accessible. There is a way to do this as well but I think there is some simpler Python program structure lesson that I'm sure someone smarter than I is typing right now.

Comment: Where do you expect `sizeGreater` in function `main` to come from? BTW, the two `return` statements in `generate_numbers` won't do what you expect them to do.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't assigned the variables when you call `generate_numbers()`. Also, your return statements don't do what you think they do.

Instead, do `sizeLess, sizeGreater = generate_numbers()` and make `generate_numbers()` return `return (sizeLess, sizeGreater)` (a tuple).

So, now you unpack the tuple that is returned from `generate_number()` by setting them again. You can then call `difference_numbers` with the newly assigned variables:

```
import random

def main():
    another = 'y'

    while another == 'y' or another == 'Y':
        again = raw_input("Would you like to generate 1000 random numbers? (Enter y for yes and n for no)")

        sizeLess, sizeGreater = generate_numbers() #unpack the tuple
        difference_numbers(sizeGreater, sizeLess)


def generate_numbers(): 
    numbers = []
    for value in range (1000):
       numbers.append(random.randint(1,100))
    print (numbers)

    numbers2 = [i for i in numbers if i>=50]

    sizeGreater = len(numbers2)
    print ("The numbers at or above fifty are:", sizeGreater)

    numbers3 = [i for i in numbers if i <=50]

    sizeLess = len(numbers3)
    print ("The numbers at or below fifty are:", sizeLess)

    return (sizeLess, sizeGreater) #return a tuple

def difference_numbers(sizeGreater, sizeLess):

    total = sizeGreater - sizeLess
    print total


main()
```